# Calling Fragment Method from Activity - NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to call a method which is in my fragment from my main activity and I get:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.activity.MyDayFragment.getTaskText()' on a null object reference
```

main activity:

```
I have this import:
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TaskDialog.TaskDialogListener  {
public MyDayFragment fragment;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button dialogbutton = findViewById(R.id.dialog_button);
        dialogbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openDialog();
            }
        });

        BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);
        //MyDayFragment fragment = (MyDayFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_myday);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                new MyDayFragment()).commit();

    }

 protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        MyDayFragment fragment = (MyDayFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_myday);
    }

@Override
    public void applyText(String task) {
        tasktext = task;
        fragment.getTaskText();
    }

}
```

the fragment:

```
public void getTaskText(){
        //taskText=((MainActivity)getActivity()).getMyData();

    }
```

mainactivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"></FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialog_button"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

FragmentMyday where the ID is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_myday"
    android:tag="mydaytag">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/topll"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp">
        <TextView
```

I'm not sure what to understand from the error, that the fragment doesn't exist? that it's not created yet?
I have edited and added the XML and onCreate from the MainActivity.Hope it helps

Comment: Looks like `getSupportFragmentManager`  failed to `findFragmentById` when called from `onStart`.

Comment: I suppose so, the id is correct tho, I've checked it many times( and its also autocompleted when I start writing it

Comment: Did you add the fragment statically in your XML or add it in your code? Post your activity layout and your `onCreate` method. That might help in getting an answer.

Comment: The `R.id` that you pass in `findFragmentById()` is the ID for the `ViewGroup` that the `Fragment` is transacted into, not one in the `Fragment`'s layout. Where is the `<ViewGroup>` with ID `fragment_myday`? Also, how are you loading `MyDayFragment`? That is, are you loading it dynamically in code with a `FragmentTransaction`, or with a `<fragment>` element in the `Activity`'s layout?

Comment: @LeoAso  I have edited and added the code .. any ideas now?

Comment: @MikeM. I have added the XMLs and the onCreate code, I'm not sure if its static or not or how the ViewGroup works.

Comment: Look at your `replace()` call. That's the ID you'd use in the `findFragmentById()`; i.e., `R.id.fragment_container`.

Comment: This is incorrect: `MyDayFragment fragment = (MyDayFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_myday);`.  You should not be declaring `fragment` as a local variable.  Indeed all of the commented out attempts are making the same mistake.

Comment: @Stephen C my bad but isnt my variable global?

Comment: `MyDayFragment fragment = ...` – Putting the type in front of it declares a new, local variable that is totally different than the field. Remove `MyDayFragment` from the beginning of that line. You'll still need to fix the `R.id`, too. (Good catch, @StephenC.)

Comment: Yes.  You do have an instance field named `fragment`.  But the statement that I noted is declaring a *local* variable that shadows the instance field.  Since the place where you are using `fragment` is using the instance field, you end up accessing a variable that hasn't been initialized ... and that causes an NPE.

Comment: @StephenC indeed, IT WORKS
problems were:
1) variable was declared 2 times
2) the id was "fragment_container" not "fragment_myday"

Answer (score 0):

indeed, IT WORKS 
problems were:
 1) variable was declared 2 times 
2) the id was "fragment_container" not "fragment_myday"